# Trying to update the value of one xml element based on the value of another

Tags: xml, xslt

Long time user of this site without registering. Now I have found an issue which, whilst i'm sure is simple to solve, i cannot see any relevant material on any of my searches!

My question is simplified with this xml example:

```
<root_element>
 <content>
  <content-detail>
    <name>TV Show Name</name>
    <value> Father Ted </value>
  </content-detail>

  <content-detail>
    <name>Airing Status</name>
     <value> Cancelled </value>
  </content-detail>

 </content>
</root_element>
```

in this entirely fictional example, lets suppose i wanted to write a XSL transformation that would update Father Ted to 'Father Ted -- CANCELLED'.

I can update all TV Show names, but am having trouble getting XSL to understand that it should only update the TV Show Name value element if the value of Airing Status is Cancelled.

Please help i have been stuck on this for hours!!!!

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="value[../name='TV Show Name']">
        <value>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="../../content-detail[name='Airing Status']/value = ' Cancelled '">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>- Cancelled
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </value>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first template is the "identity transform" that merely copies input to output.

The second template matches only `value` elements whose `name` is `TV Show Name`.  It produces a `value` element with its text set to the desired string depending on the value of `Airing Status` in the same `<content>` block.

Note: You may have to adjust the tests if there's any variation in the whitespace around the `' Cancelled '` value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that is push-oriented, is a bit more straightforward in terms of template matches, and works with any amount of whitespace around your values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template
    match="content[content-detail
             [normalize-space(name) = 'Airing Status']
             [normalize-space(value) = 'Cancelled']
           ]
           /content-detail[normalize-space(name) = 'TV Show Name']/value">
    <value>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(), ' -- CANCELLED')"/>
    </value>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```